# ERROR: Named volume "mongodb:/data/db:rw" is used in service "mongo" but no declaration was found in the volumes section

Tags: mongodb, docker

I just start learning Docker recently. Trying to set up a service that stores database.

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
    - 27018:27017
    volumes:
    - mongodb:/data/db

volumes:
  mongo:
```

As I run `docker-compose up .`, I got this error:

```
ERROR: Named volume "mongodb:/data/db:rw" is used in service "mongo" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
```

And I did create my named volume mongodb outside. Running `docker volume ls` would give me:

```
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     mongodb
```

Any ideas? Thanks alot.

Comment: In the service `volumes:`, the name `mongodb` needs to match the name under the top-level `volumes:` block.  Compose will managed the named volumes and you don't need to separately `docker volume create` it.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the quick reply. I have fixed the problem as pointed out. Now when I'm truing to run compose again, I have the following error:

ERROR: No such service: .

I don't even know what service "." is

Comment: Just `docker-compose up`.  You don't need an extra `.` at the end.

Comment: @DavidMaze Ahh got it. I thought the dot means I'm showing docker where my compose file is

Answer (score 16):

For named volumes you should have a  "volumes" key on a same level as "services", and any named volumes you are using in your services have to be listed under the "volumes" key (where you missed).

in your case :

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
    - 27018:27017
    volumes:
    - mongodb:/data/db

volumes:
  mongodb:
```

*Just a reminder :* anonymous volumes, and bind mounts don't need to be specified here.

hope this helped you :)